# PHP: what is --enable-zend-multibyte configure option for?

Tags: php, configuration

What is exactly --enable-zend-multibyte option for when you ./configure PHP?

Comment: There's some info at http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-internals/10bjtjztcw/enable-zend-multibyte

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is to be able to detect if PHP scripts are Unicode/Multibyte encoded or not (UTF-8 always works and does not need this setting).

I've found this information in this article [http://devzone.zend.com/article/2693](http://web.archive.org/web/20090909152420/http://devzone.zend.com/article/2693) (archived copy, the article itself is outdated).

Comment: "are Unicode encoded or not" is extremely vague. Are there details regarding its implementation?

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 4):

It is a prerequisite for [declare(encoding)](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php) handling.

Apart from that, I have filed a bug about the lack of documentation for this: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52348

Answer (score 0):

The configuration option --enable-zend-multibyte is part of the zend scripting engine and used for auto-detection of Unicode encoded scripts and files. It looks for BOM (byte order marks) in the begining of the file and uses that to figure out the encoding.

Comment: I don't think it is a part of Zend Framework actually. Because Zend Framework is a collection of PHP scripts ;)